# Replace everything from a starting statement to the end of column in one of the tables in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `table1` in a MySQL database called `new_world`. 
There is a lot of garbage attached to the end of many rows that I need removed. I'm asking for assistance on creating an SQL statement to remove it.

My goal is to remove everything following:

`;<br />    for(i = 0; i ' +<br />  google_ads`

and everything after that, in `names` column. The contents inside the `names` column looks like below:

```
Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.

Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.

Hey man, how you doing? Hey man, how you doing? Hey man, how you doing?
;<br /> for(i = 0; i ' +<br />  google_ads
Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.

Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.
```

So, I want to change the above contents to the below format  (i.e. do not touch the codes before `;<br />   for(i = 0; i ' +<br />  google_ads` and clean everything after that):

```
Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.

Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.....Hello World.

Hey man, how you doing? Hey man, how you doing? Hey man, how you doing?
```

Could you please help me if you know the right query to solve this problem?

Comment: This question lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Please include the [relevant parts of the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain how your results differ from the desired results. Include any error messages you receive. Please read this [advice on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Comment: @Mihai, could you please provide a similar solution with `SUBSTRING_INDEX`?

Comment: @AdiInbar, could you please review the question and let me know if you need more information?

Comment: @Apiah Could you please at least try to solve the problem yourself? Could you please at least look for the documentation of the function and try to use it to solve your issue? (Please read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com) )

Comment: @Apiah Post your efforts... we have no idea what have you done to solve it.

Comment: Also, posting attempted solutions and explaining what results you're getting and how they differ from the desired results helps others understand what you're trying to accomplish much better than just describing your goals.

Comment: The sample data you've posted is unclear. Is each line the value of the column in a separate row? If so, I don't know what you mean by "everything *following*". There's no concept of "following" in the rows of a database table, that's like saying "up" and "down" in intergalactic space. Is there and ID column that numbers the rows, determining the order? If so, don't leave things like that to inference--you have to ***say*** it. **Pay attention to Jon Skeet's Golden Rule!**

Answer (score 2):

Based on what your asking, I think this might fix your table:

```
UPDATE table SET names=LEFT(names, INSTR(names, ';<br /> for(i = 0; i') - 1) WHERE names LIKE '%for(i = 0; i%'
```

I get the string location of what your searching for `INSTR()`, and get all characters to the left of it `LEFT()`, but only if it contains a certain string.

Comment: thank you Craig, I got this error: `#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'INSTR' `

Comment: Oops, I forgot the comma between names and the string. @Apiah

Comment: thanks again for your help, unfortunately the query deletes everything in the post, everything including before and after the `;<br />  for(i = 0; i ' +<br />  google_ads`, what I'm looking for is to delete everything starting and after the above statement and don't touch anything behind the statement.  is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Oh, I think i finally understand now, you want to keep the google_ads bit, but not everything after that @Apiah?

Comment: yes everything including google_ads bit and after that,

Comment: Ok, I realized I was missing a bracket. Try the update code above. @Apiah

Comment: thanks again for your help, still the query deletes all everything even before the google_ads bit and returns an empty column,